# Deleting from "Table1" if a condition is met in "Table" 2 SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, conditional-statements, sql-delete

I'm making a little messaging application in PHP using a SQL database but have faced a small problem. I will try explain this as best as possible so here goes...

I have a table called "users" as following:

```
ID | Username | Password | Email 
-------------------------------------------
1  | Account1 | Pass 1   | email1@mail.com
2  | Account2 | Pass 2   | email2@mail.com
```

I then have another called "friends" as following:

```
UserID | FriendID
------------------
   1   |     2
```

So what I need is a query that will delete A row from the "Friends" table if a condition is met in the second table.

Example:

```
DELETE FROM 'friends' WHERE UserID = 1 AND (users.Password = $Password WHERE users.ID = 1)
```

I hope that was a good enough explanation but I'm finding this difficult to explain.

Comment: Is this MySQL or another DBMS?

Comment: Can you describe in English (as opposed to code) what you're trying to do? Like "I'm trying to get all the friends of a user, but only if that user provided the proper password"?

Comment: @corsiKa Sorry if you didn't understand.. In English I'm trying to make an SQL query that will delete a row from the friends table if the user provided the right password.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM 'friends' 
WHERE UserID IN (
    SELECT UserID 
    FROM users 
    WHERE Password=$Password 
    AND UserID=1
)
```

Should work. You don't need to have the UserId field listed twice, it would be redundant.

Comment: Would this code work?

`function DeleteFriend($UserID, $FriendID, $Password){
$Query = "DELETE FROM 'rabbit_friends' WHERE UserID IN (SELECT ID FROM rabbit_users WHERE ID = ? AND Password = ?) AND FriendID = ?";
if($Statement = $this->Connection->prepare($Query)){
$Statement->bind_param('isi', $UserID, $Password, $FriendID);
if($Statement->execute()){
$Statement->close();
return true;
}
}
}`

Comment: @user1807226 - That seems to be valid, as long as `rabbit_friends.UserID` is the same as `rabbit_users.ID`